# Android - CheckBox onDraw keep Alpha and Transparency

Tags: android, checkbox, alpha-transparency

I have a *LinearLayout* with couple views inside plus a **CheckBox**. When I do change the alpha of root view, all child will change the color transparency of themselves.

**What I am trying to do:** Extend *CheckBox* view so it ignores all changes on Alpha and color transparency, set from the parent.

When I call:

```
root.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

I want all the child to dim, but not my custom CheckBox.

How can I achieve this extending CheckBox?

**Note:** *setAlpha()* is not called inside the custom CheckBox, but *onDraw()* is.

Comment: Have you tried overriding setAlpha so it does nothing?

Comment: Yes, i did override it. setAlpha() is not called. What is called is onDraw()

Comment: So that is probably what should have happened.
You should either call setAlpha directly to other children, or wrap other children with a ViewGroup and set alpha to that

Comment: @gilgil28 how can i force inside onDraw() to set #FF(currentColor)?